# How to Indicate the End of a Column Value in Find and Replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-update

I need to update my MySQL database. I have a table of schools with a column called `name`. Some of the school names abbreviate specific words. E.g. "SCHOOL" is abbreviated as "SCH". I would like to replace all occurrences of "SCH" with "SCHOOL". I have used the following UPDATE command already in SQL:

```
UPDATE `schools`
SET `name` = replace(`name`, ' SCH ', ' SCHOOL ')
```

It worked great, however there are many schools in the database that end in " SCH" which were not updated due to a lack of a space after the " SCH". How would I go about replacing all occurrences of this trailing " SCH" string without replacing strings such as "JOHN SCHULTZ HIGH" with "JOHN SCHOOLUTZ HIGH"? Is there a character that indicates the end of a value in a column? E.g:

```
UPDATE `schools`
SET `name` = replace(`name`, ' SCH<END>', ' SCHOOL')
```

where  would indicate that there are no more characters after SCH in that column's value. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem, because you would want to replace only the last SCH in 'JOHN SCHULTZ SCH'.

Two possibilities The first one just works for the ending SCH:

```
UPDATE schools
SET name = left(name, length(name) - 4)
where name like '% SCH';
```

The second works for all SCH:

```
UPDATE schools
SET name = trim(replace(concat(name, ' '), ' SCH ', ' SCHOOL '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE `schools`
SET `name` = replace(`name`, ' SCH', ' SCHOOL')
 WHERE name LIKE '%SCH'
```